# Passing a variable to URL parameters using JQuery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url-parameters

I have a function which currently passes an account code (derived from a combo box) to the server.  Currently it does this by sending the request in the body - I need it to send as a URL parameter.  So for example the URL should be:

```
localhost:1234/myProject/WebApp/Data?accountCode=Full
```

Assuming full is selected.

My code below works as a request body but my attempts to amend it to submit as a URL request have failed.

```
 accountSelected: function () {
                var saccountCode = $("select#accountcombo").val();
                var stringAccountCode = saccountCode.toString()
                console.log("Account is: " + stringAccountCode);
                var myURL = "WebApp/Data";
                $.ajax({
                    url: myURL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "accountCode": stringAccountCode
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                })
```

I have been looking at using $.param but couldn't get anything to work and also read on other questions about using `$.get` but when I change my code above to a `"GET"` i get an error
`"Request method 'GET' not supported"` - the server is expecting a POST request.  Any way i could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Type varies on the method that you use on your form. If post method then type should be post also..

Comment: did you try this ? `url:"myURL?accountCode="+stringAccountCode`

Comment: @SandeepNayak You have a typo, should be `var myURL = "WebApp/Data?accountCode=" + stringAccountCode ;` or `url:myURL+ "?accountCode="+stringAccountCode`

Comment: @Pavlo: Agree. You are right. I didnt notice the `myURL` variable.

Comment: I've tried this but i get 400 error - bad request.  Is this not possible to achieve using jquery's '$.param' - or url request parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
URL: "localhost:1234/myProject/WebApp/Data?accountCode="+stringAccountCode
```

Appending number of parameters you want example

```
?accountCode="+stringAccountCode+"&aa="+someAccount
```

Comment: Is there a way of displaying the result in the URL bar - at the moment i can view it in console and i get
'Error: myProject/WebApp?accountCode=Full'
I believe the error is unrelated but i wanted to display the result of the POST in the URL bar which doesnt seem to happen

Comment: You are trying to do the ajax which happen instead of POST pls try the GET that's the error. What you trying is GET method `$.ajax({
                    url: myProject/WebApp?accountCode=Full,
                    type: "GET",
                    
                    dataType: "text",
                })`

Comment: Okay thanks, the key bits work - i still need to use a POST - but can get away without sticking the URL in the bar - so long as the correct data is returned.
Cheers
Also thanks to Sandeep and Pavlo who went down the same route.

Comment: Just a note in case someone else comes across this, shouldn't encodeURIComponent be used here as well. Granted an account number is unlikely to have characters needing escaped.